# FollowRedirection is not working after submitting the login form in Symfony2 Test

Tags: forms, symfony, testing

I'm using SF 2.55 functional test. 
I don't know why submiting succesfully the login form I'm being redirect to an unexpected route...

My configs:

**config_test.yml**

```
 #imports:
    - { resource: config_dev.yml }

framework:
    test: ~
    session:
        storage_id: session.storage.mock_file
    profiler:
        collect: false

web_profiler:
    toolbar: false
    intercept_redirects: false

swiftmailer:
    disable_delivery: true
```

**#security.yml**

```
form_login:
                login_path:  login
                check_path:  login_check
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                default_target_path: /es/panel
```

My test:

```
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('submit')->form();
    $crawler = $client->submit($form, $formData); //ok, the route is login_check
    $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isRedirect(), 'no login redirect'); //ok redirect 
    $crawler = $client->followRedirect();  // redirect is  /en/login !!!! so assertion fails
    $this->assertEquals('/es/panel', $client->getHistory()->current()->getUri());
```